# Unable to access the adobe application shared pdf file in android application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am working android application development process and I am sharing pdf file from Adobe app to my android application. I am getting shared pdf file URI as follows

> Android.Net.Uri fileuri =
>   (Android.Net.Uri)Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);
>
> fileuri i am getting as    {content://com.adobe.reader.fileprovider/root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads/sample.pdf}
>
> string filePath = fileuri.Path;
>
> filePath I am gettings as root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Download/sample.pdf
>
> File.Exist(filePath)--> returns false

I don't what exactly the reason behind not accessing the pdf file
please help me to access the Adobe shared file in my android application

Comment: doesn't this 2 line lok strange for you `string filePath = fileuri.Path;

filePath =root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Download/sample.pdf`? You assign `string filePath = fileuri.Path;` first, and then immediately overwrite it with `filePath =root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Download/sample.pdf`. And ofcource you can't access `root_external/data/data/` because it likely does not exist

Comment: Thank you for your response. filePath =root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Download/sample.pdf is the filepath result from fileuri.Path.I am not overwriting. please see my edited post above

Comment: You are already getting a `content://` url, what are you trying to do with the pdf?

Comment: I am trying to post that pdf to the server through my android application

Comment: `root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Download/sample.pdf` is not *real* file path. It is virtual. You can't use it as a path. Instead use the URI you are given. You can read file from URI

Comment: in adobe application, Local tab the pdf file exists in /data/user/0/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

By the following code, I am able to get adobe application shared pdf file as a stream and saving into android application path

```
using (var stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(fileuri))
{
       byte[] fileByteArray = ToByteArray(stream); //only once you can read bytes from stream second time onwards it has zero bytes

       string fileDestinationPath ="<path of your destination> "
       convertByteArrayToPDF(fileByteArray, fileDestinationPath);//here pdf copied to your destination path
}
     public static byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream)
        {
            var bytes = new List<byte>();

            int b;
            while ((b = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
                bytes.Add((byte)b);

            return bytes.ToArray();
        }

      public static string convertByteArrayToPDF(byte[] pdfByteArray, string filePath)
        {

            try
            {
                Java.IO.File data = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                Java.IO.OutputStream outPut = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(data);
                outPut.Write(pdfByteArray);
                return data.AbsolutePath;

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```